# HTML hidden type in PHP

Tags: php, html, curl

I am worrying about giving a unique organisation ID within a HTML hidden field.

Is it possible to insert an hidden value within the php code so that it doesnt have to be shown within the HTML code.

**HTML**

```
<input type='hidden' name="organisationID" value="12321232123123">
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

//Initialize the $query_string variable for later use
$query_string = "";

$error = "";


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if ($_POST['first_name'] == "") {
        $error .= "Please enter in your first name.<br>";
    } 
    elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['first_name'])) {
       $error .= "Please enter in a valid first name.<br>";
    }

    if ($_POST['last_name'] == "") {
        $error .= "Please enter in your last name.<br>";
    } 
    elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['last_name'])) {
       $error .= "Please enter in a valid last name.<br>";
    }

    if ($_POST['email'] == "") {
        $error .= "Please enter in your email address.<br>";
    }
    elseif (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$_POST['email'])){
        $error .= "Please enter in a valid email address.<br>";
    }

    if ($_POST['company'] == "") {
        $error .= "Please enter in your company name.<br>";
    }
    elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST['first_name'])) {
       $error .= "Please enter in a valid company name.<br>";
    }

    if (isset($error) && trim($error) != "") {
        // echo $error;
    }
    else {
       if ($_POST) {
          // Initialize the $kv array for later use
          $kv = array();

          // For each POST variable as $name_of_input_field => $value_of_input_field
          foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {   
             // Set array element for each POST variable (ie. first_name=Arsham)
             $kv[] = stripslashes($key)."=".stripslashes($value);
          }

          // Create a query string with join function separted by &
          $query_string = join("&", $kv);
       }
       // Check to see if cURL is installed .
       if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
          die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
       }

       // The original form action URL from Step 2 :)
       $url = 'https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8';

       // Open cURL connection
       $ch = curl_init();

       // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($kv));
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);

       // Set some settings that make it all work :)
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

       // Execute SalesForce web to lead PHP cURL
       $result = curl_exec($ch);

       // close cURL connection
       curl_close($ch);
    }
};

?>
```

Comment: `<input type="hidden">` is hidden from users but not from _page source_ functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have 1 edit field to keep track of, you can use the $_SESSION variable.

in your form do

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['orgId'] = '123123123123123';
```

Then in your PHP, you can access that code there. Note you'll need

```
    session_start();
    $orgId = $_SESSION['orgId']; // You may want to perform an isset check before using it just in case.
    // and
    session_destroy(); // Destroy session When you're done (Not REQUIRED, but good practice)
```

Comment: This method won't work, say when you have multiple records and say multiple edit/delete buttons, you will always have to use hidden fields for that

Comment: True, but the poster doesn't mention this as a requirement